# Warning "Attempt to read property 'feeds' on null" using post update function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Working on own plugin for WordPress have a page where I need to update post object. But after excuting command `wp_update_post` I have an error

```
Warning: Attempt to read property "feeds" on null in /Users/myusername/Local Sites/ecomlocal/app/public/wp-includes/post.php on line 5014
```

Here is my class structure skipping non necessary parts of this page

```
<?php

class SampleClass {

    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function init() {
        if ( ! is_admin_page( 'overview' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->hooks();

        $this->update_product();
    }

    protected function hooks() {
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'enqueues' ] );

        add_action('run_admin_view', [ $this, 'output' ] );
    }

    public function enqueues() {
    }


    private function update_product() {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['product-change-submit']) ) {
            return;
        }

        $product_id = intval($_POST['product_id']);
        $product_name = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_name']);
        $product_sku = sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_sku']);
        $product_short_desc = wp_kses_post($_POST['product_short_desc']);
        $product_desc = wp_kses_post($_POST['product_desc']);

        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $product_id,
            'post_title' => $product_name,
            'post_content' => $product_desc,
            'post_excerpt' => $product_short_desc
        ));
    
        update_post_meta($product_id, '_sku', $product_sku);
    }

    public function output() {
        
        ?>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="' . $product_id . '" />
            <div>
                <div class="editor-row">
                    <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
                    <input id="product_name" type="text" name="product_name" value="' . get_the_title() . '"/>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-row">
                    <label for="product_sku">SKU</label>
                    <input id="product_sku" type="text" name="product_sku" value="' . $product->get_sku() . '" />
                </div>
                <div class="editor-row">
                    <label for="product_short_desc">Short description</label>
                    <textarea id="product_short_desc" name="product_short_desc">' . $product->get_short_description() . '</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-row">
                    <label for="product_desc">Description</label>
                    <textarea id="product_desc" name="product_desc">' . get_the_content() . '</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit save_quick_edit_data_callback">
                <button type="submit" name="product-change-submit" class="button button-primary">Save</button>
                <button type="button" class="button" onClick="cancelEdit(' . $product_id . ')">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
<?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `$this->update_product();` too early, I guess just after you've constructed the object? It is then calling wp_update_post before everything else has finished loading, in this case the $wp_rewrite global which isn't available until the setup_theme event.

You should probably call update_product() from the init hook instead:

```php
add_action( 'init', [ $this, 'update_product' ] );
```